# Combine a nav with sticky position in a layout with 100vh (child of) body element?

Tags: html, css, sticky

In my page i prefer not to style the  directly, but use a wrapper instead. Wrapper has `min-height: 100vh`. See the layout here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ql9hVzG5mc.

**Question**: how to place a sticky `<nav>` with that layout?

**Solution 1**: place the `<nav>` as direct child of the `<body>`. Works, but a vertical scrollbar appear because the 100vh doesn't take the `<nav>` height into account. Please note that i don't know the height of the `<nav>`, so the wrapper can't be `min-height: calc(100vh - 32px)`, to say. Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/VGiGCnRrn0

**Solution 2**: place the `<nav>` as direct child of the `<header>`. It doesn't work because, AFAIK (I may be wrong), the element should be a direct child of the body.

**Solution 3**: any ideas?

```html
<body>
  <nav class="bg-orange-500 sticky top-0 p-4">
    nav
  </nav>
  <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-red-500">
    <header class="flex-shrink-0 bg-slate-500 p-4">
      header
    </header>
    <main class="flex-auto flex-shrink-0 bg-lime-500 p-4">
      main
    </main>
    <footer class="flex-shrink-0 bg-violet-500 p-4">
      footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `min-h-screen` with the body element instead and the rely on flexbox to extend the content

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<body class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
  <nav class="bg-orange-500 sticky top-0 p-4">
    nav
  </nav>
  <div class="flex flex-col grow bg-red-500">
    <header class="flex-shrink-0 bg-slate-500 p-4">
      header
    </header>
    <main class="flex-auto shrink-0 bg-lime-500 p-4">
      main
    </main>
    <footer class="flex-shrink-0 bg-violet-500 p-4">
      footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I'd like to avoid setting flex on body, as many plugins (i.e. notification plugins) will add elements as direct child of body. Flex direction column may break those :/

Comment: @gremo use another container inside the body then ... in my example simply change body with div and it's done

Comment: Thanks so much, he works putting the sticky as direct child of the wrapper. Now I understand how it works!